# How to calculate time difference for grouped data(MYSQL 5.6)

Tags: mysql

I would like to get time difference for group data, please have a look at table:

```
id | session_id | event | created

1  | 101  | START | 2010-01-10 09:30:10
2  | 102  | START | 2010-01-10 09:31:10
3  | 101  | END   | 2010-01-10 09:32:10
4  | 103  | START | 2010-01-10 09:35:10
5  | 102  | END   | 2010-01-10 09:38:10
6  | 103  | END   | 2010-01-10 09:39:10
7  | 101  | START | 2010-01-10 09:39:10
8  | 102  | START | 2010-01-10 09:42:10
9  | 103  | START | 2010-01-10 09:39:10
10 | 102  | END   | 2010-01-10 09:45:10
```

Output should be as follow :

```
session_id | time_count

 101  | 2 (minutes)
 102  | 7 (minutes)
 103  | 4 (minutes)
 102  | 3 (minutes)
```

So here i want to count the time difference for each sessions which does ended successfully, not for those session which did not ended.

Any help will be great, Thanks in advance

Comment: Store dates in the correct format. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Comment: Dates are correct in my table, sorry for that i have entered wrong date in example

Comment: Please check it now, Thanks

Comment: I'll wait until the other points are addressed, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT session_id,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,started, ended) as time_count
FROM(

    SELECT session_id, Tstart.created AS started, 
            (
                SELECT created
                FROM mytable Tend
                WHERE event = 'END' AND Tstart.created < Tend.created AND Tend.session_id=Tstart.session_id
                GROUP BY session_id
            ) AS ended
    FROM mytable Tstart
    WHERE event = 'START'
) t
WHERE ended IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY session_id
```

Returns:

```
| session_id | time_count |
|------------|------------|
|        101 |          2 |
|        102 |          7 |
|        102 |          3 |
|        103 |          4 |
```

Test it : [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b1c32/14)

Comment: Because of large amount of records sub query is taking time to execute, but logic is working properly as per my requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thomas

Comment: You should have  have your 3 columns indexed : session_id, event and created